# Where do I declare x and y to make this c code work?

Tags: c, undeclared-identifier

I have:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int sum ( int x, int y );

 main ()
 {
 int theSum = sum (10, 11);
 printf ( "Sum of %i and %i is: %i\n", x, y, theSum );
 }

 int sum ( int x, int y )
 {
 return x + y;
 }
```

However, when I compile and run it says x and y are undeclared? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line three all you have done is declare a function `sum` which takes two parameters, both integers, called `x` and `y`. You haven't declared any *variables*. Those parameters can only be referred to inside the function itself. Below is a simplification which will help you at this stage, but you should try to read a basic programming book. "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie is a fine place to start.

**Variables** are chunks of memory that you refer to by name. They can take on any value (of their type) during the life of your program - hence the name 'variable'. They must be declared before you use them; you do this by telling the compiler their type and their name. `int  a` means 'reserve me a block of memory big enough to hold any integer, and let me refer to it later with the name `a`'. You can assign values to it: `a = 10` and you can make use of it: `a + 20`.

You need to understand the difference between parameters and variables to get what's going on here. A function's parameters are basically variables which exist only during the life of that function. Here's your `sum` again:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Notice how the top line looks just like a variable declaration `int x`. That's because it is. `x` and `y` are variables you can use in the function.

You call `sum` by passing in values. The compiler, in effect, replaces `x` and `y` in your function with the values you pass in. In your case, you're passing **literals**: 10 and 11. When the program reaches the call to `sum`, the parameters `x` and `y` take on the values 10 and 11, so the return becomes `return 10 + 11;` which is of course 21.

Just remember that the **parameters** `x` and `y` only exist in that function. You may only refer to them within your function. Why? Because each pair of curly braces `{` and `}` define a **scope**, and anything declared within that scope can only be used within that scope. That includes variables and parameters.

So, here is a more complete example. I have changed the letters so you can see the different ways you use variables and parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum ( int x, int y );

main ()
{
   /* We declare our variables */
   int a;
   int b;

   /* We assign values to them */
   a = 10;
   b = 11;

   /* We pass them as parameters to your sum function */
   int theSum = sum (a, b);
   /* And we use them as parameters again, in a call to the printf function */
   printf ( "Sum of %i and %i is: %i\n", a, b, theSum );
}

int sum ( int x, int y )
{
   return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation and to all answers. Very difficult choosing between these as best answer. Tanks again everyone! Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

declare x and y right before the call to sum:

```
main ()
{
int x = 10;
int y = 11;
int theSum = sum (x, y);
 printf ( "Sum of %i and %i is: %i\n", x, y, theSum );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to declare x and y in main, so that you call sum(x,y) rather than calling it on 2 literals. At the moment, x and y are only defined in the function sum.

Answer (score 1):

No, you haven't. You just told the compiler that the function `sum` takes two ints. You could have written that as

```
 int sum ( int , int );
```

Therefore you should write:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int sum ( int , int );

main ()
 {
     int x = 10;
     int y = 11;
     int theSum = sum (x, y);
     printf ( "Sum of %i and %i is: %i\n", x, y, theSum );
 }

 int sum ( int x, int y )
 {
 return x + y;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The x and y variables are only passed as arguments to the function. You would not be able to reference those in the main function. If you wanted to, it would be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum ( int x, int y );

main ()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 11;
    int theSum = sum (x, y);
    printf ( "Sum of %i and %i is: %i\n", x, y, theSum );
}

int sum ( int x, int y )
{
    return x + y;
}
```

This should work. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` you’re declaring neither `x` nor `y`—you’re just passing in the literal values 10 and 11. Outside the scope of the `sum` method, neither name has any meaning. Quick fix:

```
main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 11;
    int theSum = sum(x, y);
    // etc.
```